# What is the correct status code when a POST request successfully logs out a user and redirects to the home page?

Tags: node.js, express, redirect, http-status-code-302

**Environment:** Node.js, Express

**Question:** What is the correct status code for a situation in which a POST request successfully logs out a user and redirects the client to the home page?

**Background:** I use a POST request to log out clients.  At the end of a successful log out I use, `return res.redirect('/')` to forward the user to the home page.

When I checked the headers in Dev Tools I saw that Express was by default sending a [302 status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302).  However in my situation I'm not sure if that's right because resources have not been moved temporarily or permanently.  When an internal redirect happens due to the normal operation of a server what is the correct status code to send?

> Request URL: https://www.example.com/logout 
> Request Method: POST 
> Status Code: 302 
> Remote Address: 1.1.1.1:443 
> Referrer Policy: strict-origin

Below in the response header it shows

> location: /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [303 - See other](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/303). The "resource" has not been moved because there is no resource to speak of - you're displaying a related page, which is, however, not the representation of the hypothetical "logout resource".